# Grails: render select tag from controller with multiple attributes

Tags: groovy, grails3

From controller i am render the tag output using the below code.

```
List output = someService.getLetterListByProject(params.projectId);
render g.select(name:params.name,from:output,id:params.id,class:params.classes,optionKey:params.optionKey,optionValue:params.optionValue,noSelection:params.noSelection)
```

but i am getting an exception while calling. Which is shown below.

```
Exception in getLetterListByProject in controller  LetterGenerationController :groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.entrySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: toSet(), getBytes(), every()
```

Comment: Do you need all the attribute?

Comment: Is `output` definitely a List & not a String? e.g. is `someService.getLetterListByProject` throwing an exception & returning a string message?

Comment: The exception you have is for render g.select

Comment: yes, the exception happening while calling render g.select and i need all the attributes to work.

Comment: by using only the attributes `name` and `from` the code is working properly. but in my case i also  need  `class`, `optionKey`, `optionValue` attributes.

Comment: try adding the attributes one by one

Comment: how we can add the attributes one by one?